# Раздача страниц с React кодом на golang

Tags: html, reactjs, веб-программирование, golang, веб-сервер

Ранее раздавал html-страницы на сервере на golang с помощью следующего кода

```go
t, err := template.ParseFiles("build/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
        return
    }
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
```

И он прекрасно работал, если в html не было react-скриптов. Сейчас попробовал создать страницу с помощью React, выполнил  `npm run build` и при попытке раздать итоговый `index.html` из папки `build` выходит пустая страница. Каким образом можно заставить golang правильно раздавать страницы с react-ом? Спасибо большое за ответы!

Comment: а покажите код, как вы раздаете новые страницы

Comment: для golang'a (или для любого http сервера) страницы что с reactom'ом, что jQuery, что с любым другим модным фреймфорком выглядят абсолютно одинаково - просто набор байт. И все. Поэтому, скорее всего ошибка в другом месте (например, запрашивается не та страница). Или фреймоворк хочет каких то особых, трепетных хедеров/таймингов. Но это маловероятно

Comment: @SeniorPomidor точно так же, как и в коде выше. То есть просто прописал путь к новому index.html и пытаюсь его раздать

Comment: мне кажется, что скрипты лежат рядом с index.html. попробуйте добавить загрузку скриптов `http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor да-да! проблема была именно в этом, я просто не знал, что всю статику нужно отдельно подгружать. Спасибо огромное:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего скрипты лежат рядом с index.html. Необходимо добавить загрузку скриптов, например так

```
http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/path/to/scripts"))))
```